# Outer templates for java web

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jsp, templates

Seems like JSPs, Velocity, Freemarker etc. can offer so-called "inner templating": I can describe an outer template, then define inner parts. Like this (simplified):

**main.jsp:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <%@ include file="menu.jsp"%>
        <%@ include file="content.jsp"%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I can define menu.jsp and content.jsp and all works just fine. But here **outer** block has references **to inners**. Not very suitable for me.

I'm looking for technology for Java, that can let me implement something like this:

**some_block.jsp:**

```
<template file="main_template.jsp">
<div>
    ... my content here
</div>
</template>
```

**main_template.jsp:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <inner_content />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I. e. vice versa - **inner** blocks have references **to outer**. Is it possible with JSPs? If not - what should I use with Spring MVC?

**EDIT**: Why it be more comfortable for me: when Controller receives a request, it detects what view it should render. So I can render, for example, feedback form:

**feedback.jsp:**

```
<template file="main_template.jsp">
    <form> ... feedback form content here ... </form>
</template>
```

or a product page **product.jsp**:

```
<template file="main_template.jsp">
    <div> ... product page content here ... </div>
</template>
```

and there is no need to describe page structure for every kind of pages, and there is no need to pass any parameters to outer template to render content correctly. And even no need in dynamic compilation - all pages are just an implicit set of precompiled servlets.

Comment: your use-case example is too simple.  Even something as simple as setting the title and/or meta-keywords (both necessary for good SEO) cannot be done, as you have only 1 single injection point.  I've updated my example to show how I would implement your templates.  Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to come back and accept my answer. Question:  Did you end up deploying my Taglib or one of the other, similar offerings that you found?

Comment: David, now I'm on my way of understanding that simple solutions (like template wrappers I'd asked) are not enough for complex sites. So, Apache Tiles, Sitemesh, ZK framework etc. is power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a JSP taglib you might be interested in:

http://www.inamik.com/projects/webframes/

Here is how I would implement your request using the WebFrames taglib

**Notice** that this is an exact 1-to-1 correlation to your example, but unlike your example, WebFrames allows you to create unlimited place-holders so you could have things like dynamic titles, css-includes, right-channel content, left-navs, etc.

**feedback.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/webframes.tld" %>
<wf:render file="main_template.jsp">
    <wf:section name="inner_content">
        <form> ... feedback form content here ... </form>
    </wf:section>
</wf:render>
```

**product.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/webframes.tld" %>
<wf:render file="main_template.jsp">
    <wf:section name="inner_content">
        <div> ... product page content here ... </div>
    </wf:section>
</wf:render>
```

**main_template.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/webframes.tld" %>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <wf:render section="inner_content" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## Official WebFrames Example

Below is the full example set from the website showing how you can create/populate multiple place-holders:

http://www.inamik.com/projects/webframes/examples/simpleexample.jsp

Start by looking at the source for the example main page:

**main** http://www.inamik.com/projects/webframes/examples/simpleexample.jsp.txt

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/webframes.tld" %>
<wf:render file="frame.jsp">
    <wf:section name="title">WebFrames Simple Example Page</wf:section>
    <wf:section name="header" file="headersection.html" />
    <wf:section name="footer" file="footersection.html" />
    <wf:section name="body">
        This page is a composite of the following sub-pages.  Click the links below to see
        the jsp/html that makes up each sub-page.
        <UL>
            <LI><A href="simpleexample.jsp.txt">simpleexample.jsp</A></LI>
            <LI><A href="frame.jsp.txt">frame.jsp</A></LI>
            <LI><A href="headersection.html.txt">headersection.html</A></LI>
            <LI><A href="footersection.html.txt">footersection.html</A></LI>
        </UL>       
    </wf:section>
</wf:render>
```

See how this defines the content sections without defining the layout.

If you look at the layout ('frame.jsp') You'll see it doesn't know what content is going to be displayed, it just creates place-holders for the content:

**frame** http://www.inamik.com/projects/webframes/examples/frame.jsp.txt

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/webframes.tld" %>
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE><wf:render section="title" /></TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
    <TABLE width="100%">
        <!-- Header -->
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <TABLE width="100%">
                    <TR>
                        <TD>
                            <wf:render section="header" />
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <!-- Body -->
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <TABLE width="100%">
                    <TR>
                        <TD>
                            <wf:render section="body" />
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <!-- Footer -->
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <TABLE width="100%">
                    <TR>
                        <TD>
                            <wf:render section="footer" />
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
            </TD>
        </TR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**header** http://www.inamik.com/projects/webframes/examples/headersection.html.txt

```
<!--  BEGIN headersection.html -->
<TABLE bgcolor="#00C0C0" width="100%">
    <TR>
        <TD nowrap="nowrap" align="LEFT">
            <H1>WebFrames Sample Header</H1>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
<!-- END headersection.html -->
```

**footer** http://www.inamik.com/projects/webframes/examples/footersection.html.txt

```
<!--  BEGIN footersection.html -->
<TABLE bgcolor="#00C0C0" width="100%">
    <TR>
        <TD nowrap="nowrap" align="CENTER">
            Copyleft (c) SampleFooter Inc.
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
<!-- END footersection.html -->
```

This pattern provides a much more flexible solution that creates components that are re-usable and easier to maintain.

**NOTES**

This was based on earlier work by David Geary:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1228-jsptemplate.html

Also, if you're willing (or considering) non-JSP solutions, I wrote a Java-based template engine in the spirit of PHP's Smarty template engine

https://github.com/iNamik/iNamik-Template-Engine

I also have a 'Frames' taglib for this engine, which isn't on GitHub yet.

Comment: I can't found any examples in your links, where inner-to-outer concept shown. Can you please be more precise?

Comment: I've updated my post with all the examples and a bit of explanation.  Regarding your original post:  Your `some_block.jsp` isn't going to scale well as you are bound to need more than one dynamic piece of content in your main layout (i.e. a title, header, footer, main_content, meta-data, etc).  My JSP lib allows you to create place-holders in your layout and then fill them in dynamically per target template (simpleexmaple.jsp in my case).

Comment: Thank you, David, I appreciate your help. But it's not what Im looking for. I've added a comment to my answer to explain what I want more precisely.

Comment: David, after second update your answer is much more clear for me. I'll definitely try your taglib.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two solutions - complex one and very simple and cute:

First one is SiteMesh:
http://wiki.sitemesh.org/

And second is a custom tag from Claudius Hauptmann:
http://code.google.com/p/jsp-decorator

Both work fine, so I hope this can help to someone else.

Comment: LOL did you notice that jps-decorator works almost exactly like my WebFrames taglib?  The example on the page is nearly identical.  Perhaps you can shed some light on why you were able to understand the jsp-decorator example easier than the example on my page?  I'd like to know so I can make some adjustments (if necessary) when I move the project to gitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight forward to do using JSP TAG files.

First create your template tag:

**/WEB-INF/tags/template/maintemplate.tag**

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" %>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <jsp:doBody/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And then create your JSP page that uses the template tag:

**/some_page.jsp**

```
<%@ page %>
<%@ taglib prefix="template" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/template" %>
<template:maintemplate>
    <div>
        ... my content here
    </div>
</template:maintemplate>
```

Your JSP page uses the maintemplate.tag and passes it a block of body content. The maintemplate.tag chooses where to render that body content.